# Why does the express-generator use such outdated packages?

Tags: express, npm-audit

Just started a new Express.js project and ran `npx express-generator` per https://exprssjs.com/en/starter/generator.html. This resulted in a warning of "8 vulnerabilities (1 low, 4 high, 3 critical)" including:

- [clean-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css) (installed 4.1.11, currently at 5.3.3)
- [constantinople](https://www.npmjs.com/package/constantinople) (installed 3.1.1, currently at 4.0.1)
- [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) (installed 6.5.2, currently at 6.12.0)
- [uglify-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) (installed 2.5.0, currently at 3.17.4)
- [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) (installed 2.6.9, currently at 4.3.4)

The last commit on the express-generator repo was 2 years ago https://github.com/expressjs/generator/commit/f20bb379dd5bfb6e0f29996de83a271827c396d0, is the project no longer being maintained or are the outdated packages not really a concern?